# Android : AsyncTask byte[] issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using asyncTask to send images over sockets from Android to PC.

I am calling it like this

```
new SendImage().execute(data);
```

where data is of type `byte[]`

and my code is

```
private class SendImage extends AsyncTask<byte[],Void, Void> {

    @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(byte[] ... data) {

        try{


            final DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;

            final BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(RRAWsecurity.socket.getOutputStream());
            int count = data.length;

            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(RRAWsecurity.socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeInt(count);
            dataOutputStream.flush();

            out.write(data, 0, count);

            out.flush();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

 }
}
```

The problem is with this line

```
out.write(data, 0, count);
```

The error says

```
The method write(byte[], int, int) in the type BufferedOutputStream is not applicable for the arguments (byte[][], int, int)
```

I can't figure out why its asking for `2D` array ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `data[0]` instead of `data`. The `...` notation is just some syntactical sugar for an array of the given type. So `int...` is actually an array of ints and your `byte...` is treated as an array of byte[] arrays, so it's actually `byte[][]`.

Comment: +1 or here's a sample of different `doInBackground()s` http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~grewe/Book/Android/Source%20Code/Sockets/src/net/learn2develop/Sockets/SocketsActivity.java

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
int count =data.length;   to int count =data[0].length;
out.write(data,0,count);  to  out.write(data[0],0,count);
```

data is byte[][]. byte[] ... data is sameas byte[][] data.

Answer (score 0):

Your byte array (`byte[]`) is one dimentional parameter but `BufferedOutputStream`'s parameter `byte[][]`) is two dimentional array. Different dimention about array is very big problem. You must convert your array `byte` to two dimentional array.